# Reading Excel 2013 using ssis 2012 Data Flow source

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

There was an attempt to read excel 2013 file using ssis 2012,but can not find a corresponding excel connection.Under excel connection manager ,it lists Excel version from  3 to excel 2007.So how to read 2013!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is exactly what needs to be done. I installed the Office 2007 OLE DB driver and then you will be able to connect to the Excel 2013.

Here are the links:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Answer (score 1):

You could save excel data to CSV and then import it by SSIS